# Forwarding a user directly to credit card processing page on PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible to forward a user to PayPal (no account/non member page) during a checkout process? For instance, when I forward any user to PayPal, the user sees a checkout screen where PayPal asks for the PayPal account. At the bottom of the login options, there is an option to pay directly by credit card for new users. I would like to be able forward the user to that option from my php code by using a variable. Maybe I can use a variable in my php code after cmd in the following code:

```
$sActionURL = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$aFormData = array(
            'cmd' => '_xclick-subscriptions',
            'lc' => $locale 
        );
```

I am not sure whether PayPal allows this, but I already know that my user does not have a PayPal account. So it would be better to forward the user to that page.
Thank you.

Comment: I bet Paypal would like to take the opportunity to gain a new customer by offering them to create a new account. If you don't like it, offer another payment provider.

Comment: I guess you did not understand what I wrote.

Comment: You want to jump to a page one or more steps later in the Paypal process. Unless Paypal clearly documents how to do it, it won't work. You probably have scanned their documentation for hints. If their answer is not "yes", you must assume "no", or simply try to jump to a later URL. But I guess you did not understand that I wrote that Paypal does not want you to do this. They want to offer the user you are sending to create an account with them - so the next time you send this user, he would have an account.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PayPal Express Checkout, you can set `LANDINGPAGE` parameter:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

> (Optional) Type of PayPal page to display. It is one of the following
>   values:
>
> ```
> Billing – Non-PayPal account
> Login – PayPal account login
> ```

Website Payments Standard doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is not possible Paypal does not allow this to be done via their API, you having an account with them is the core of their business so they are obviously not going to let you bypass them trying to rope you in (yes I'm not a fan of Paypal)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Source from [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/WAX_landing-outside)

Comment: @Andy that is only for Express Checkout although i had forgotten about it but from his code it doesn't appear he is using express checkout.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by not supplying the customers email address to the paypal payment page. If you don’t supply an email address it doesn't auto fill the login form and displays the credit/debit card payment form.